# How to transfer data between two Android devices using Beacon?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am trying to send text data between two Android devices using beacon. I am using Android Bluetooth Low Energy APIs to develop the application. But i am stuck in reading the data.

Whenever i am trying to set Values to the Characteristics , the other device not able to receive the data. The Characteristics getValues return null.

I have already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903325/android-ble-characteristics-getvalue-returns-null/) question in other thread in **Stackoverflow**. But still again i am conveying my queries in Graphical format.

[image]

This is the above image which explains the scenario.

Please suggest me some solution and technique to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most "Beacon" devices only transmit messages via advertising packets and don't accept connections.  (The name kind of hints at this)  Some beacon devices allow you to connect to them to modify the message they're transmitting, but I don't think there's any Beacon devices that make connections to other devices to relay messages.

So, while you may be able to connect to the Beacon to set a message, the Beacon will then send that message as a public broadcast that any device can pick up.  But again, most Beacon devices only transmit a fixed code that can't be altered.

Answer (score 0):

There exists two types of devices called as Bluetooth Smart Ready and Bluetooth Smart devices. Beacons are Bluetooth Smart devices which can only broadcasts the data but it can never be a Transceiver.